# Can HTML tags inherit the class of a parent/enclosing tag?

Tags: html, css, inheritance

Is there a way to specifically style only the tags inside a wrapping tag? For example, I want to style only `<td>` within tables of class "wide".

HTML:

```
<table class="wide">
<tr>
<td>Entry 1</td>
<td>Entry 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
...
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS (or something along these lines):

```
td.wide {
    /* styling */
}
```

I want to have all the `<td>` elements for "wide" tables styled but a table like `<table class="small"> ... </table>` would not have its `<td>` elements styled. I would like to avoid adding `class="wide"` to every `<td>` element in all the wide tables.

Note: I'm not looking to do this specifically for `<table>` and `<td>` elements. I'd like to know the proper way to do this in general. The example could be styling all `<p>` elements enclosed in a `<div>` of a certain class.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Can HTML tags inherit the class of a parent/enclosing tag?

No. Classes are not inherited.

> Is there a way to specifically style only the tags inside a wrapping tag?

A [descendant combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators)

```
selector-of-container [space] selector-of-target-within-container
```

> I would like to avoid adding `class="wide"` to every `<td>` element in all the wide tables.

```
table.wide td { /* rules */ }
```

Answer (score 4):

This is basic CSS.

Your table has a class of `.wide` and you want to style the td elements within it.

```
.wide td {
yourstyles;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, I figured it was something simple.

Answer (score 2):

With your HTML layout, this is very easy.

```
table.wide td {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, thats not how css works

You could do this

```
table.wide td {
}
```